# Why does my code ( ZipOutputStream ) saves empty file in ZIP?

Tags: java

I have a simple code that is supposed to make txt file zipped, though txt file has some content, it's empty in a zip folder ( it has 89 bytes ( like buffer ) but all are just spaces.
The interesting part is that if I write

```
byte[] buffer = Files.readAllBytes(path);
```

my code is working.

I am new to java and would appreciate your help a lot. Because I trully don't understand what I am doing wroing.

```
 public class Test {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\10\\Desktop\\ds.txt");
                 ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(fis);
                 ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(Files.newOutputStream(Paths.get("C:\\Users\\10\\Desktop\\ds.zip")))) {
    
    
                byte[] buffer = new byte[fis.available()];
    
                zos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry("ds.txt"));
    
                zis.read(buffer);
                zos.write(buffer);
                zos.closeEntry();
            }
```

Comment: Consider to use the Zip File System: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/io/fsp/zipfilesystemprovider.html Required Java 11 module: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/jdk.zipfs/module-summary.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the text file is not zipped yet, don't use a ZipInputStream to read it. Just use the FileInputStream, or even better the [NIO.2 File API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileio.html) (you're using it already to create the ZipOutputStream but not to create the InputStream).

There is even a file system provider for the NIO.2 File API to read/ write to Zip files using the same API: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/io/fsp/zipfilesystemprovider.html (For Java 11+ the following module is required: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/jdk.zipfs/module-summary.html)

Also make sure to use try-with-resources for the OutputStream as well, not just the InputStream, to properly close the stream in the finally block.